# Postgres Not Using the Index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-performance

For some reason, Postgres isn't using the index I defined - I'm likely missing something obvious, but I've beaten my head against the wall for a while and would love your advice.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."useractivity" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('useractivity_id_seq'::regclass),
  "userid" int8 NOT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  "channel" varchar(32) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
  "action" varchar(64) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
  "details" varchar(256) COLLATE "default",
  CONSTRAINT "useractivity_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,
  CONSTRAINT "action_user_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("userid") REFERENCES "public"."user" ("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE)
  WITH (OIDS=FALSE);

CREATE INDEX  "activity_user_idx" ON "public"."useractivity" USING btree(userid ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "idx_useractivity_action" ON "public"."useractivity" USING btree(userid ASC NULLS LAST, "action" COLLATE "default" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "idx_useractivity_action2" ON "public"."useractivity" USING btree("action" COLLATE "default" ASC NULLS LAST, userid ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "idx_useractivity_action_date" ON "public"."useractivity" USING btree(userid ASC NULLS LAST, created_at ASC NULLS LAST);
```

Query:

```
SELECT useractivity.userid,
        count(*) AS num
       FROM useractivity
      WHERE (useractivity.action= 'sent')
      GROUP BY useractivity.userid
```

Output of the EXPLAIN for the query:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=15846.78..15880.29 rows=3351 width=8)
->  Seq Scan on useractivity  (cost=0.00..14987.83 rows=171791 width=8)
    Filter: ((action)::text = 'sent'::text)
```

Why isn't Postgres taking any of my indexes and is instead doing a sequence scan on 171 thousand rows??

Comment: Probably because of the type conversion.  Possibly because an index would not help performance of the query.

Comment: Removed type coercion - still not using the index.

Comment: What is the cardinality of the `action` column? If there are 100k activities that are `sent` out of 170k, there is no point to use index.

Comment: Just because an index is there doesn't mean that the optimizer will blindly use it, sometimes consulting an index will be more expensive than scanning all the rows. Query optimization is a bit of a dark art, there's a reason that big databases tend to have DBAs to take care of them.

Comment: You guys were absolutely right - when I looked at cardinality of the column, I saw that the majority of the records had action = 'sent' - so there was no point for Postgres to use the index. Thanks so much.

Comment: This is related to Postgres not having implemented [Loose index scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan)

Comment: Which version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: Or more probably to this feature, implemented in 9.2: [Index only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#Index-only_scans)